# Samsung CLX-3185 installation

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

I've downloaded the universal driver from Samsungs website.  It's the universal driver named CLX-3185.  I've downloaded it, but I don't know how to install this driver.  Does anyone know how I install this driver?  I need help!  Thanks, Leonard Johnson

Answer (score 2):

This is a Windows driver, you can't use it in Ubuntu.

You don't need to download any driver to use this device as a printer.

If you want to use it as a scanner you will need to download the Unified Driver (Linux) from the Samsung site.

This driver is a compressed file to install it:

- Double click on it to open it
- Extract it to your home folder (click on the extract button, select your home dir).
- Now in your home dir (the dir that you see when you click on the folfer icon in the launcher) there should be a folder called Cdroot.
- Double click cdroot.
- Double click Linux.
- Double click install.sh

This should get the driver installed.